# Docker Alpine dotnet Core 2.2 Console App every response content-length 0

Tags: docker, .net-core

i´m trying to run a dotnet Core 2.2 Console Application in an Alpine .net Core Docker image.

On my windows computer the application is running - on the docker container its running too but every response is status 200 with empty content.

Container logs looks good.

This is my DockerFile:

```html
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-alpine as base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 11007


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine as builder

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/Common
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

WORKDIR /app/DataAccess
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

WORKDIR /app/ERPSystem
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

WORKDIR /app/GlobalLibrary
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

WORKDIR /app/Hoster
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

WORKDIR /app/Model
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

WORKDIR /app/Service
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

WORKDIR /app/Hoster
#RUN ["dotnet", "build"]
RUN dotnet build -c Debug -o /result

FROM builder AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o /result


FROM base AS final
COPY ["settings.json", "/usr/share"]
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /result .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Hoster.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the controllers are located in a other assembly (next to startup.cs in a folder "Controllers"). On linux I have to use "            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(somecontrollerclass).Assembly);" instead of "            services.AddMvc();" (both is working on windows).